# Error "invalid type (closure) for variable..." when defining a function, using survey package

Tags: r, function, survey

I'm trying to define a function for running a simple contingency table of proportions, on survey data, using R and the "survey" package.

Here is the function, where the variable (named "svyvar") and the survey design (named "design") are being passed in as arguments.

```
prop_tab <- function(svyvar, design) {
  svytable(~svyvar, design = design, Ntotal=100) 
}
```

Here is me calling the function, on the "Gender" variable" and the "Survey Design" design:

```
prop_tab(Gender, Survey_Design)
```

This results in the following error message:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = weights ~ svyvar, data = model.frame(design)) :
> invalid type (closure) for variable 'svyvar'

For reference, here is how I have specified the survey design, although I am confident there is no error there, it is solely with the variable:

```
Survey_Design <- svydesign(ids = ~1, data = 201920, weights = 201920$Weight)
```

I am assuming the error is caused by the way the variable works in the "svytable" function, with the "~".  Is there any way to get this to work? I can't provide the data as it's from my work.

Comment: You don't need to provide the real data, but please do provide something with the same form.  The issue almost certainly depends on where it is finding `Gender`, and you haven't shown us that.

Comment: The `survey` package has a function (type = closure) called `svyvar` but you have used that as a variable in your formula `~svyvar`. R does not find the variable `svyvar` in your environment so it goes to the function which will not work.You should generally avoid giving your data objects the same name as function objects.